# integer solutions combinations

Tags: combinations

> How many solutions are there for this equation:
>   $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 17$$ when they are all non negative integers and $x_1 > 6$.

I was thinking to solve the original equation then subtracting $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 11$ from it. *Would this be the appropriate path?*

Answer (score 2):

Almost.  Since $x2$ and $x3$ are allowed to be zero, you should subtract $7$ from $x1$ and solve $x1+x2+x3=10$ in the nonnegative integers.  That way all the variables are treated the same.

Comment: I don't really get why it's 7. If x1 was instead x1 >= 6 would we then use 6?

Comment: Because the minimum allowable value for $x1$ is $7$ and the other variables are allowed to be $0$.  We want to allow the new $x1$ (I would have given it a different name) to be $0$ as well.  Yes, if you had said $x1 \ge 6$ I would have subtracted $6$.  In addition, if you had said $x2$ and $x3$ had to be positive instead of nonnegative I would have subtracted $6$.